# Why does everyone in Firefly speak Chinese?

Tags: firefly

In the television series "Firefly," it seems like every person on every planet speaks Chinese.  Conversations often transition randomly between English and Chinese, and even the computer alerts are in both languages.

Why?  **Is there an in-universe explanation for this?**  What about out-of-universe *(The director's girlfriend is Chinese?  The writer is a huge fan of classic Bruce Lee films)*?

Comment: Think of it like being like how "Employees must wash hands" signs are always in both both English and Spanish even when there are no hispanic employees.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

From [Firefly Timeline](https://web.archive.org/web/20061118011043/http://www.mts.net/~arphaxad/firefly.html):

> The United States and China, the two great superpowers of the Earth,
>   gradually grow together and form the Anglo-Sino Alliance (though their
>   empires remain separate), rather than killing each other as originally
>   predicted. In a somewhat ironic reversal, the American Empire annexes
>   England.
>
> [Firefly website and "A Brief History of the Universe, circa 2507
>   A.D." In an interview on the site, series creator Joss Whedon first
>   described some of this background to account for the mix of cultures
>   in the Alliance, and the pre-production memo gives further details.
>   This history is implicit in the design of the Alliance flags seen in
>   "The Train Job" and "Bushwhacked," a combination of the present-day
>   flags of the two countries in question.]

Basically the culture of Firefly is a fusion of Chinese and American culture because those are the superpowers that "won".

Comment: Which is strange given how very few Chinese characters (people not the writing) we see in the TV series.

Comment: @SystemDown perhaps they didn't 'win' by that much?

Comment: @Pureferret - And yet their culture is infused everywhere? I don't buy that. I love the series to bits, but that (as well as the sheer number of habitable worlds in one system) has always bothered me.

Comment: @System: They terraformed the planets to *make* them hospitable.  As for why the outer-planets are not frozen, see [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2773/how-is-it-that-the-outer-planets-in-firefly-are-not-frozen)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Pyrodante: Is there any out-of-universe explanation for this?  Did the writer ever explain why he chose Chinese over, say, Japanese or Russian or German?

Comment: @SystemDown Original drawings of Kaylee in *Firefly: The Official Companion I* suggest that she was originally going to be Asian. Still, you'd expect that more Chinese would have appeared regardless of the casting switch.

Answer (score 12):

My answer comes in several parts:

1. China and the US are the only two countries with the right mixture of high population, high capital and high education to take over half the world. If Earth unified, it makes sense that it would be under their influence.
2. Given the in-universe importance of China politically and culturally, the lack of notable Chinese actors and background extras is illogical, but I'm going to try to defend it anyway. There are several histories that would result in widespread Chinese influence without many Chinese people. Take, for example, the strong French influence in North and Central Africa and the Caribbean. The colonial system spread their culture without spreading their race. This is less likely in the case of a massive country such as China, but imagine the world leading up to the Anglo-Sino alliance. China would have linguistic influence on Europe, Africa, Asia and Micronesia because of their financial and military resources, and eventually everyone would want to learn Chinese like everyone wants to learn English today. Maybe there was a plague in China. Maybe the Chinese decided they wanted to keep Earth when people went to the stars, and they were the ones who eventually ran it into the ground. There are more possible solutions than "Joss Whedon is racist".
3. Creative reasons
   The two countries that really own the Western genre are China and the US, with slight concession to Korea. American Westerns and Chinese *wuxia* both feature lone, highly skilled, highly principled but disillusioned warriors that often live outside the law protecting a small coterie of trusted friends. Sound familiar?

Comment: This sounds like guesswork, not official canon.  Do you have any sources for these claims?

Comment: I concede it's guesswork, applying general political and critical theory to the facts given in the series. I'm fairly new to Stack Exchange, is this discouraged? The most guessworky parts are only meant to provide a counterpoint to the "there are no Asian actors, thus Whedon is racist" claims, not actually prove anything.

Comment: Some of this answer is good but "The lack of notable Chinese actors and background extras is illogical and reprehensible" was uncalled for. There were no Innuit or French actors either...

Comment: I have issues with Richard's argument, but agree that the writing was biased. Edited to be more logical argumentative

Comment: "The colonial system spread their culture without spreading their race." Excellent point.

Comment: -1 For guesswork. Even when dressed up with "I concede it's guesswork, applying general political and critical theory" No application of political and critical theory assumes that the conditions of the writer's world *today* will necessarily hold centuries hence.

Answer (score 7):

And to get around FOX's language restrictions, a lot of the Chinese is actually cursing. But because the show was geared towards Americans they let it slide, as no one would know what they were saying.

Comment: source​​​​​​​​?

Comment: Topless Robot did an article about the curse phrases in Firefly. http://www.toplessrobot.com/2010/11/fireflys_15_best_uses_of_chinese_profanity.php

Comment: This, while true (I read that article a while back), is also a bit false. As someone who has learned Mandarin (since watching Firefly as a kid), and having re-watched the show the insults, while crude (in both meaning and pronunciation) I would tend lean towards it was also a means to show the crassness of the crew and the environment/sub-culture we as viewers find ourselves in.

Answer (score 3):

I like the reasoning that compares prevalence of Chinese language and lack of Chinese (speaking) characters to European colonialism. 
Many new Canadians speak English(or French) as a second language because of the colonial past of their native countries. I work with Francophone Congoliennes, Haitiennes, and Moroccans as well as Anglophones from India, Kenya and Indonesia (yes, she also speaks Dutch). 
Learning a second language in school because it is useful in the work world is normal pretty well anywhere outside of the UK and the USA.

Of course, it doesn't explain why a lot of the Chinese is actually swearing. (Yes, I do know about the Fox censors.)

Answer (score -3):

The main reason is... The show seems to have a Chinese sponsor for the show. Just like one of the Iron man movies was almost fully sponsored by them!

Comment: Do you have a source that proves this/names the Chinese sponsor of the show?

Comment: This is pure conjecture at its finest. And frankly, hilarious as the Chinese in that show is poor and purely cusswords (again, poor wordage there too). If it was in fact sponsored by the Chinese then the phrases would be grammatically correct as opposed to a string of words that are easy to say, and vaguely resemble an insult.