# Chinese in Serenity?

Tags: languages, firefly, serenity

One of the things that makes the world of the *Firefly* TV series distinctive is the intermingling of English-speaking and Chinese cultures. All of Serenity's crew appear to be fluent in both English and Chinese, and we frequently see signs written in both languages.

However, in the film *Serenity* I didn't notice any Chinese being spoken at all. There were a few bilingual signs, but none of the casual Chinese cursing that's in pretty much every episode of the TV series.

Did I miss something? **How much Chinese is spoken in the film *Serenity*?**

If I'm right and there's none, **why?** Did the cast refuse to bother learning Chinese lines for the sake of a single film? Did this aspect of the TV series get so much criticism that they decided to exclude it? It seems strange for this distinctive *Firefly* gimmick not to appear in the franchise's swan song.

Comment: Related: [1](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9865/why-does-everyone-in-firefly-speak-chinese), [2](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73873/is-everyone-in-firefly-fluent-in-chinese-or-do-they-only-know-chinese-slang), [3](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51528/how-accurate-is-the-chinese-spoken-in-firefly), [4](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131648/how-many-crew-members-of-the-serenity-actually-read-chinese)

Comment: @RogueJedi Yep, already seen all those and voted on most of them.

Comment: My cynical side says they didn't think characters speaking Chinese would sell tickets.

Comment: @Kevin - Likely, or just that in a film format, there is definitely less time for it, and it (seemed like? to my eyes) had a pretty packed script as it was.

Comment: Didn't Kaylee say "谢谢" near the beginning, or was that in an episode?

Comment: @Cascabel You'll have to transliterate or translate that for me; I'm afraid I have zero knowledge of Chinese.

Comment: @Randal'Thor "Thank you" It sounds like shíh-shih.

Comment: @Cascabel Can't find it in [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Serenity.html), but that thing is quite hard to read.

Comment: There are at least 20 instances of people speaking Chinese in Serenity; http://fireflychinese.kevinsullivansite.net/title/serenitymovie.html

Comment: @Valorum Turn that into an answer?

Comment: http://www.browncoats.com/?ContentID=42e83b412a309

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There were at least ***11*** instances of Chinese pidgin that made it into the theatrical cut of Serenity. I've listed them below for ease of searching, along with what each statement actually means.

---

Given that the *average* number of Chinese phrases in [each 44 minute episode](http://fireflychinese.kevinsullivansite.net/title/index.html) is approximately *16*, it would appear that there **were indeed fewer Chinese phrases *per minute* (by almost three quarters) in the film than in the TV shows.**

That being said, when you take into account the cut scenes and all the extra Chinese signage (and subtract the two extremely Chinese-heavy episodes that drag the average up from 12.1 to 16.5) it's not quite as obvious.

> 1) TEACHER:
>    **BAI-tuo, AN-jing-eedyen!** "We will enjoy your silence
>   now!" [Please be quiet!]
>
> 2) MAL:
>    **"DONG-luh-MAH?" Ni cho lyen, yo may yo?** *"Are we clear
>   here?" [Do you have a worried face?*]
>
> 3) WASH:
>   **"Ai-yah. Tyen-ah..."** "Merciless hell..." [Ah, oh God...]
>
> 4) ZOE:
>   **Da jee-ah tzwo sha!** Everybody sit down!
>
> 5) MAL:
>   **"Nee TZAO ss-MA? Nee-YOW wuh-KAI CHANG?"** "You wanna bullet? You wanna bullet right through your throat?" [Are you looking to die? You
>   want me to shoot?]
>
> 6) [BEAUMONDE] MAN, partially cut:
>   **"PEOW-liang de shaojie, nee GOO wuo HUHnee SHANG-hao. Wuh HWAY wrongnee shungkai roo hua..."** "Pretty lady, hire me for the night
>   and I'll open you like a flower..." [Beautiful young lady, if you hire
>   me to have an affair with you, I'll let you fully bloom like a flower]
>
> 7) [SHAMED GENTLEMAN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7idn3PcKBM):
>   **Wuo hun {diou lyen}. Wuo may yo chr Fruity Oaty Bar.** "I am very ashamed. I didn't eat a Fruity Oaty Bar."
>
> 8) JAYNE:
>   **"Go HWONG-TONG."** "Enough of this nonsense."
>
> 9) WASH, mostly inaudible:
>   **"Juhguh JEE HUA jun kuhPAH!"** "There's nothing about this plan that isn't horrific!" [This plan is truly horrible!]
>
> 10) RIVER:
>   **"RUNtse de SHANG-DEE, ching DAIwuhtzo"** "Merciful God please take me away"
>
> 11) RIVER:
>   **"WUOshang mayer, maysheen, BYEN shr-to"** "I will close my ears and my heart and I will be a stone"

---

> There were also a number of lines that were part of the *deleted
>   scenes* found on the DVD.
>
> TEACHER, cut line:
>   **"Shuh-MUH?"** "I'm sorry?"
>
> MAL, cut line:
>   **"BEE-tzway. Wrong wuomun FAH-TSAI."** "Shut up and make us wealthy."
>
> INARA
>   **"Byen dahTAHmenduhBAY joGOluh."** "A switch to those girls' backsides is just good enough." [Whipping their [female] backs is just
>   good enough.]
>
> [BEAUMONDE] WOMAN, cut line:
>   **"Wuo DWAY-nee BOO-woon, boo-JEN..."** "I neither see nor hear you..."
>
> [BEAUMONDE] MAN, cut line:
>   **"PEOW-liang de shaojie, Booleetah, GOOwo..."** "Pretty lady, forget him and hire me..."
>
> WASH, cut line:
>   **"Wo TAI-TAI boo PEOW-liang!"** "My wife is not pretty!"
>
> INARA, cut line:
>   **"RUNtse de FWOtzoo, ching baoYO wuomun..."** "Oh merciful Buddha protect us..."
>
> <sub><sup>[Translations courtesy of BrownCoats.com](http://www.browncoats.com/?ContentID=42e83b412a309)</sup></sub>

Comment: You should probably introduce the quotes, I had no idea what the first quote box was and am only now *guessing* that it is the eleven instances of Chinese in *Serenity*, since there are eleven entries and I know the bit about Fruity Oaty Bars was in the movie...

Comment: @KRyan - Better now?

Comment: Note that the chinese part comes from the shooting script. It's not Pinyin. Therefore some of the translations are uncertain.

Comment: @Chris - Yes. Pidgin not Pinyin :-)