# In universe, why do we see almost no Chinese people in Firefly?

Tags: firefly

Firefly takes place in a universe where Chinese and American cultures have fused, as evidenced by Chinese signage, and the frequent use of spoken Chinese in the series.   Yet, for a universe that's supposedly half Chinese, there are exceedingly few appearances by people of Asian descent in the show.

I believe that out of universe, this can be attributed to deep-seated cultural and racial issues in the film and television industry.

I'm interested to know, however: is there an explanation **in universe** as to why a half-Chinese culture is so darned white?

Comment: We only saw a tiny fraction of the system?

Comment: Point 2 of [this answer to 'Why does everyone in Firefly speak Chinese?'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/50526/98028) has a theoretical answer.

Comment: Actually, according to an interview question/answer at a 'con, it just wasn't something Whedon wanted to emphasize. Wasn't racist, just wasn't an emphasis. (Of course, there are many who say that that is implicit racism anyway, so...)

Comment: "*deep-seated cultural and racial issues in the film and television industry"* - Erm, I'm pretty sure this was an American show made for a largely American audience (and hence with a cast that largely reflects the demographic of who'll be watching it). How many Western actors do we see in [Scarlet Heart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_Heart)?

Comment: @Valorum - That's a bit thin, though. *Scarlet Heart* doesn't have an in story reason to have lots of US actors. When there is one, well...the Somali pirates in *Captain Phillips*, for instance, don't represent US population demographics, for instance. There's no need to sacrifice realism in order to use whatever actors are most readily available.

Comment: Not to mention that in the case of *Firefly*, it was even more a case of availability over plausibility. Half the cast were actors Whedon had worked with before.

Comment: This is an "uncomfortable truth":  https://xkcd.com/561/

Comment: "Erm, I'm pretty sure this was an American show made for a largely American audience"... you get that Americans are also *Chinese Americans*, right?

Comment: @Lexible  - I do indeed. And Chinese Americans represent just over [1% of the population of America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Americans). If anything they're dramatically over-represented in the show (since more than 1/100 of the characters is Chinese) if you only take into account the actual demographics of the country making the show.

Comment: @Valorum (a) The 'verse is *explicitly* not America in-universe, so that last comment reads a tad off color, (b) Americans *not* of Chinese descent are also partly Chinese American in our heritage because our culture has been shaped so, from railway labor, to Chinese American literature, to Bruce Lee.

Comment: @Lexible - The 'verse may explictly have lots of Chinese people in it, but peopling a network show with an ethnically diverse cast (one that doesn't in any way reflect the potential audience) sounds awfully risky.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that what you are seeing is the result of colonization undertaken by like groups of people, either grouped by religion or race. I wouldn't expect to find large disparate demographic groups colonizing a planet.

They never visited a planet colonized by Chinese people. All they ever hit are the poor, backwater places. Obviously, the Chinese did better in than the non-Chinese population. So more the bulk of the colonization was carried out by more wealthy and stay were the money is: The core planets.

The successful culture never migrates/emigrates. It's always those less fortunate who board the boats for green shores. The people who leave as a group will almost always be those of a like mind and culture. Successful colonization by disparate groups are exceedingly rare. That scenario has played out countless times throughout human history.

Answer (score 6):

**Firefly's culture is a mixture of American and Chinese, but there's no indication that it's 50/50.**

In fact, there's plenty of evidence that American culture has been dominant.

Even among those who speak both languages fluently, **English is the primary language, while Chinese is mostly reserved for cursing.**

The flag for the Union of Allied Planets is a combination of the US and Chinese flags, but **the American flag is much larger and clearly dominant.**

[image]

Comment: You could,equally argue that the Chinese flag is more prominent with the American one forming a background , it's not entirely clear one dominates another.

Comment: I absolutely agree - the flag can be ambiguous. But I don't think the language is. They speak English all the time, compared to the infrequent Chinese.

Comment: @LevenTrek The language they use does not provide any evidence, since a show's language always depends on the target audience. I don't think that in-universe and out-of-universe can be conflated here, since shows tend to use the language of the country in which they are aired. If anything, the occasional Chinese used in their speech is a hint that there is a lot of Chinese in it. If you can cite someone actually describing the language as being mainly English, then you'll have an argument that works. Otherwise I don't think you do.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is rooted in cultural differences.  Today, the Chinese live in a strongly civilized society, and have been for a very long time; as a result their culture is hierarchy-oriented, and the people tend towards 'know your place' norms of behavior.  By contrast, America is still quite new (historically speaking), and among its people there is still a lot of 'rugged individualism' even in the more civilized areas.  I can see this sort of difference being carried over to the new planetary system.  That means those Chinese and Americans who prefer order would gravitate to the already-civilized inner planets, while 'rougher' characters would be more likely to go to the outer, 'frontier' planets - and American descendants would be rather more likely to produce 'rougher' characters.  And as @Ring says, the crew members of Serenity prefer to stay away from the inner planets (for various reasons).

Comment: This seems like headcanon rather than something rooted in the show itself. Can you offer any solid evidence to back it up (other than the absence of Chinese people, obviously)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Answers should be based on evidence from the show, official related works, or things that the show's creators have said.  Please read [answer].  Without some basis from the show, this seems to be just supposition on your part.

Answer (score -1):

If we teeter on the edge of in universe/out of universe, then Simon, River, and Kaylee are all Chinese characters, but their actors are not... at least, if the planning phase stuff in the official companion book holds that kind of weight with you.

Comment: You appear to have some nice information here but it would be improved by [edit]ing evidence.